# Windows maximizing in the wrong monitor

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, window

I have a multimonitor setup, and every time minimize, for example, Google Chrome which was in monitor 3 or 2, when i maximize it again it always puts it back in the primary monitor, which is really annoying. How can i fix that?

Comment: I should have mentioned that it did not do that a while ago

Comment: @JuliePelletier: This is not the way it works. I've worked with a multimonitor setup in Windows 10 for months/years now and Chrome has always stuck to the window it was last minimized (tangentially: or even closed) on. Today, I am faced with OP's issue. Your claim that this is intended behavior is abjectly false.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just had this issue myself. I found that I fixed it by opening a second Chrome window and dragging it to monitor 2. I hit the restore down button and at first, it restored the size and moved it to monitor 1. I manually moved it back to 2, maximized it, and then minimized it. Now, Chrome maximizes while staying on monitor 2. I even closed it, opened a second Chrome window again and now I can just move and minimize and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into you **Task bar settings** and configure it such that each monitor has its own taskbar and items or only visible on their monitor's taskbar.

So if you have Chrome open at monitor 2, if you minimize it, it will minimize to monitor 2's task bar only.

2. To keep visibility, I would disable the combining of apps and keep the labels visible, until the task bar is full.

There are several ways to 'maximize' an application. You might be telling your machine to maximize it on the specific monitor because that is the monitor you perform the action on.

Whatever your method is, everything made more sense for me after **I gave each monitor each its own task bar.**

3. If you want to use your application at monitor 2, you should start it at monitor 2. (**Does it pop up elsewhere? Drag it to target, teach windows by exiting the app on Monitor 2 (target)**. Start it again using taskbar at monitor 2; now Windows should have remembered you want it to start at monitor 2.
4. Do not start the same application at monitor 1 on the same desktop.

---

5. Use additional desktops for more complex configurations; though in your case that might get confusing fast as your other monitors will also change content. (Win+Tab; Ctrl+Win+ArrowRight/ArrowLeft) However; on your secondary desktop on monitor 1 (or B1) you can now run the same app as running on monitor A2. Windows should remember your preference per desktop.

Comment: The tips in this answer don't address the actual issue. I've worked with a shared taskbar for months now and Chrome has always stuck to the window it was last minimized (tangentially: or even closed) on. Today, I am faced with OP's issue. Nothing has changed about the setup, and the proposed settings that need to be changed according to this answer do not actually impact on which monitor a window is maximized.

Answer (score -1):

Try moving your application to the preferred monitor, clicking the 'Restore Down' button in the top right, and then the 'Maximize' button.